# How should you say an app is coming to the app store prior to being approved?

Tags: ios-appstore, itunes-store

This is likely a silly question, but I can't seem to find anything official on this subject.

Often on pages for upcoming games and applications, you'll see an image that states "Coming to Apple Store" (Along with similar mentions of FaceBook, Windows Phone, Android, etc).

My application is currently in development and I *intend* to being it to the app store, however, I am not yet an approved developer.

So, on the application's webpage, should I simply mention that I intend to port it to iOS, or is it alright to use an 'official' "available on the app store" image accompanied by a "coming soon" overlay banner? I wouldn't want to step on anyone's toes, but likewise, I'd like to let it be known that the game will more than likely be available on iOS upon completion.

Comment: You should provide a link in your question to the game, gives you some traffic and gives us a good example of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could state that your game is *under development for iOS*, and if you are waiting for approval you can state it is *submitted to the App Store* or that it is *Waiting approval for the App Store*.

In Apples documentation it is known as '[Submitting Your App to the Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html)'